# IllegalArgumentException not catched

Tags: android

A very strange error...I register and unregister a receiver in the onResume() and onPause() methods. Here is the code in the onStop() method:

```
    try{
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.sdCardReceiver);
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        Log.d(MyOwnLife.LOG_LIFEGALLERY, "ActivityVideo - onStop unregisterReceiver:"+e);
    }
```

And I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: myownlife.pigeau.activityVideo.ActivityVideo$SdCardReceiver@405443f8
```

I catch the error...but my application crashes anyway...any idea ?

Here is the full log:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {myownlife.pigeau/myownlife.pigeau.activityVideo.ActivityVideo}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: myownlife.pigeau.activityVideo.ActivityVideo$SdCardReceiver@405443f8
at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:2434)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleWindowVisibility(ActivityThread.java:2506)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: myownlife.pigeau.activityVideo.ActivityVideo$SdCardReceiver@405443f8
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:851)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:342)
at myownlife.pigeau.activityVideo.ActivityVideo.onStop(ActivityVideo.java:224)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1170)
at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3884)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:2431)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you please add the logcat output as well

Comment: Why don't you use your favorite debugger to find out what is happening?

Comment: Seems you are trying to do some custom things  :
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050730/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered

Comment: Let's see the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that exeption you have got is not thrown from your code, or even from Activity class code, but has been created at some system level library, so there is no way to handle it properly.

Here you find workaround:
[Android - BroadcastReceiver unregisterReceiver issue (not registered)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421449/android-broadcastreceiver-unregisterreceiver-issue-not-registered)

Comment: This solution would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a local broadcast then try this

```
 onPause(){
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
  }
```

Comment: I wish I could give Avinash a million upvotes!!!  This problem drove me nuts for several hours, and this simple trick fixed the issue entirely!!!