# Weird crash in multiwindow with Samsung devices

Tags: android, crash, multi-window

After searching a lot, I can't find a solution for this crash

```
Exception Backtrace:
1   android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher  LoadedApk.java, line 882
2   android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver  ContextImpl.java, line 1294
3   android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver   ContextWrapper.java, line 601
4   com.android.internal.policy.MultiPhoneWindow$VideoCapabilityReceiver.unregister MultiPhoneWindow.java, line 2679
5   com.android.internal.policy.MultiPhoneWindow$MultiPhoneDecorView.onDetachedFromWindow   MultiPhoneWindow.java, line 1037
6   android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow    View.java, line 15916
7   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow   ViewGroup.java, line 3385
8   android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow    ViewRootImpl.java, line 3837
9   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie ViewRootImpl.java, line 7086
10  android.view.ViewRootImpl.die   ViewRootImpl.java, line 7059
11  android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked   WindowManagerGlobal.java, line 424
12  android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView WindowManagerGlobal.java, line 379
13  android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate  WindowManagerImpl.java, line 140
14  android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity    ActivityThread.java, line 5187
15  android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700  ActivityThread.java, line 229
16  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage  ActivityThread.java, line 1880
17  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage  Handler.java, line 102
18  android.os.Looper.loop  Looper.java, line 148
19  android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java, line 7407
20  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java
21  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run  ZygoteInit.java, line 1230
22  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java, line 1120
```

It is happening only in samsung devices, especially this models:

- SM-G950N (S8)
- SM-G955F (S8 Plus)
- SM-A520F (A5)
- SM-J700F (J7)
- SM-N930F (Note 7)
- SM-N950F (Note 8)
- SM-A720F (A7)
- SM-G935F (S7 Edge)

with Android 6.0.1 and 7.0.

Also, I haven't added the next manifest metadata concerning the old samsung sdk

```
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.enable" android:value="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.multiinstance.enable" android:value="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.STYLE" android:value="fixedRatio"/>
```

or multiwindow categories in the activity

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks (=

Comment: you are getting error on Unregistered receiver, have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15598339/5110595)

Comment: yes, i know, but where? I am not working with com.android.internal.policy.MultiPhoneWindow$VideoCapabilityReceiver